# Problems with block syntax in Objective-C - typedef block with return type and arguments

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a block:

```
typedef id (^completionBlock)(id data, NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error);
```

And in a class method I try to populate this block with some code.

```
request.requestCompletedBlock = ^(id data, NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error){
  ...
return object;
};
```

requestCompletedBlock is of type completionBlock obviously.

I get the following error:

"Incompatible block pointer types assigning to 'completionBlock' (aka 'id (^)(_*strong id, NSURLResponse **_strong, NSError *__strong)') from 'void *(^)(_*strong id, NSURLResponse **_strong, NSError *__strong)'"

Obviously my syntax is wrong somewhere, but where?

Thanks very much,

Vb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For whatever reason, the compiler is inferring that the return type of your inline block is `void*`, not `id`.  You can force it to use a return type of `id` by putting the return type after the `^` like so:

```
request.requestCompletedBlock = ^id (id data, NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    //                           ~~
    //                        Return type
}
```

See [this page](http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/#cblocks) for a detailed description of block syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is inferring "void*" for the type of "object". You can explicitly declare the return type of the literal like so:

```
^id(id data, ...) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is correct, it's the type of your data that you got wrong.

Your `object` is of type `void*`, but your block expects you to return `id`. This means that you should either wrap `object` into, say, `NSData*`,

```
request.requestCompletedBlock = ^(id data, NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error){
    ...
    return (id)[NSData dataWithBytes:object length:numBytes];
};
```

or change the declaration of the `completionBlock` to expect a return type of `void*`.